# How to select a section of an audio track in ios using a visual control in iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I'm writing something where I'll use a portion of an audio track from a device's iTunes library to overlay over a combo of 2 videos, as such:

```
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

//VIDEO TRACK
AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, self.firstAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[self.firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *secondTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[secondTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, self.secondAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[self.secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:self.firstAsset.duration error:nil];

//AUDIO TRACK
if(self.audioAsset!=nil){
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *AudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [AudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(self.firstAsset.duration, self.secondAsset.duration)) ofTrack:[[self.audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
}
```

That last line of code take a piece of the track starting at time 0, and lasting the length of the videos combined, which makes sense.

What I'd like to do is select whatever section of the audio track I want, not necessarily from the start; and I'd like to allow the user to do do that, with the help of sliders perhaps.

What is a good way to implement this? Are there any tutorials out there with examples?

Would love any help.

Answer (score 0):

The *code* for selecting the section of audio and combining it with the view to make a single movie object is trivial. You already seem to have the hang of this. And here's an excerpt from [my own example code](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch15p669playerLayer/ch28p939playerLayer):

```
type = AVMediaTypeAudio;
arr = [oldAsset tracksWithMediaType:type];
track = [arr lastObject];
comptrack = [comp addMutableTrackWithMediaType:type preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[comptrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeSubtract(duration, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)) ofTrack:track atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600) error:nil];
```

As you can see, we're doing much the same sort of thing.

Providing an *interface* for letting the user specify what's wanted is up to you. After all, it's your app.